# use of net workdrive for access database and server

Tags: php, odbc, network-drive

I am trying to connect to access database which is there in a network drive. My server is windows 2003 and with ISS. I tried placing access database on local drive and used odbc connect in my PHP code. It worked fine. But when I moved database on to the network drive and after changing DSN I tried with UNC path and normal network drive accessing. Can any body help me in this..
I appreciate your time.